# How to change Cursor position in Console?

Tags: c#, console-application, console.readline

I wanted to use `Console.ReadLine();` in the previous line and make it display like that:

```
HeresomeText>(input)
```

Not like

```
HeresomeText>
(input)
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Write method instead of WriteLine Method:

```
 Console.Write("HeresomeText> ")
```

in addition you can use SetCursorPosition:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(int left, int top);
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely - look at the various members of the [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

In particular, you want the [`SetCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, but if you're writing a "fancy" console app you should think about the members for using colours etc too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your previous `Console.WriteLine()` statement. Change it to `Console.Write()` which does not have the linebreak.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("HeresomeText>");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```