# Erase only one already printed character from the console in c#

Tags: c#, console

So I want to create a script that first prints out values from a (pretty big) 2D array and then change one character by erasing it and printing a new one without clearing out the whole console and redrawing it because that creates flickering which is very annoying when i want to make often changes. So is there any way to replace or erase one character that has been already printed or any other efficient way to do it? I just don't want flickering.

Comment: You want to modify the console window for output that has already been displayed, without creating a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the cursor and write a space " ". (Or whatever character you want to use as a replacement.)

Answer (score 0):

To delete the last character input in the console you can use the following command:

> Console.Write("\b");

However, if you're attempting to remove a character in the middle of the string you'd have to do some clever backspacing to the character you want, and then reprint the rest of the string. You could write a loop to backspace until the character you wish to remove, add the removed characters to a stack, and pop them off to rewrite it.

The second approach would be very inefficient due to console commands being naturally slow, and also really misusing the console backspace command.

Comment: but i want to erase something that has already been printed and most likely in another line

Comment: You can move the cursor around the Console with `Console.SetCursorPosition(int, int)`.  There are other console operations you can do from there.  Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089645/how-to-change-cursor-position-in-console

Comment: Unfortunately I believe that the console is not a good I/O for what you're trying to achieve. There are plenty of better objects such as a StringBuilder and outputting the results to a file that would achieve the same thing but with more support for string modifications.

Comment: i do know about `Console.SetCursorPosition(int, int)` but i can't just move my cursor and use `Console.Write("\b \b");`, that doesn't work

Comment: @DanielSiebert outputting files to a file is a bad idea cause i want a live overview what is happening and what is StringBuilder?

Comment: @Dodison Just move the cursor and write a space " ". (Or whatever character you want to use as a replacement.)

Comment: @FilipMilovanović wow that actually helped, i didn't the the answer was so simple.